# Duplicate Billing Address to Shipping Address

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code to duplicate the entered Billing Address into the Shipping Address form:

**HTML**

```
<b>Billing Address</b>

<form>

   Address 1:
   <input type="text" id="billing_address_1">

   Address 2:
   <input type="text" id="billing_address_2">

   City:
   <input type="text" id="billing_city">

   <input type="checkbox" id="billingtoshipping_checkbox">
   <em>Check this box if Shipping Address and Billing Address are the same.</em>
   <b>Shipping Address</b>

   Address 1:
   <input type="text" id="shipping_address_1">

   Address 2:
   <input type="text" id="shipping_address_2">

   City:
   <input type="text" id="shipping_city">

</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#billingtoshipping_checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("[id^='shipping_']").each(function(){
            data=$(this).attr("id")
            tmpID = data.split('shipping_');
            $(this).val($("#billing_"+tmpID[1]).val())
        })
    }else{
        $("[id^='shipping_']").each(function(){
            $(this).val("")
        })

      }
})
```

Now I need to make it work without the `billing_` on the billing address input ids, and I can't work it out. This is due to the CMS I am using, I don't have control over the ids. The rest of the id will match the Shipping e.g. `address_1` should appear in `shipping_address_1` if the checkbox is ticked, `address_2` should appear in `shipping_address_2`, `city` should appear in `shipping_city` and so on.

Thanks for any help

Comment: you mean to say the input Id of the billing address can be anything.You don't know what will be ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Changed `change` to `click` since I prefer that event handler for checkboxes
2. Removed "billing"
3. Added `var` where needed
4. Used a ternary to shorten the code

```js
$("#toshipping_checkbox").on("click",function(){
    var ship = $(this).is(":checked");
    $("[id^='shipping_']").each(function(){
      var tmpID = this.id.split('shipping_')[1];
      $(this).val(ship?$("#"+tmpID).val():"");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Billing Address</b>

<form>

   Address 1:
   <input type="text" id="address_1">

   Address 2:
   <input type="text" id="address_2">

   <input type="checkbox" id="toshipping_checkbox">
   <em>Check this box if Shipping Address and Billing Address are the same.</em>
   <b>Shipping Address</b>

   Address 1:
   <input type="text" id="shipping_address_1">

   Address 2:
   <input type="text" id="shipping_address_2">

</form>
```